# Azure Deployment Not Using New Migrations

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I used a [tutorial from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-dotnetcore-sqldb-app) to deploy my app to Azure.

When deploying my web app to Azure, the migrations aren't applying. There is also another error saying that the table "AspNetRoles" already exsits.

It loads the initial page fine, but then when I try clicking on a different page I get this error:
[An internal server error showing that migrations haven't been updated in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW3Xu.png)

To be clear, the image is from the deployed web app, I have put it in development mode for now as those errors don't occur on my local machine.

When I test my app locally, everything runs perfectly and and the database is updated correctly with my new migrations. I expected to receive the same error but I don't.

I have tried commenting and uncommenting the lines context.Database.EnsureCreated() and context.Database.Migrate() in my Program.cs file and deploying that, but the same error occurs.

I am using the correct connection string.

I have used the SSH and followed these commands:
`cd /home/site/wwwroot`
`./migrate`
and got the error message `There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.`

Edit: I have thought the problem might be in my deplyoment on GitHub, as seen here [screenshot of github build with the dotnet bundle migration opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpa47.png). I'm wondering if it's because I haven't copied 'appsettings.json' alongside my bundle if I need to apply migrations, which is currently the main problem. I'm not sure what it means or how to do exactly that though.

Comment: Migration creates a mapping between the c# classes/properties and the database tables/fields.  Error indicates the mapping  (in client) is not matching between the client and the database.  Code is working locally so mapping is correct.  So most likely the database used locally is not the same as the database used remotely.  Or the connection is failing when use remotely.  Migration has two modes 1) Create 2) Update.  Error could be you are using Create instead of update since error says "There is already an object ...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for certain what the problem was, but I fixed it by adding `context.Database.EnsureDeleted()` and then `context.Database.EnsureCreated()` into my Program.cs.

Here's the block of code, the arrows point to what fixed my problem.

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    context.Database.EnsureDeleted(); // <-- 
    context.Database.EnsureCreated(); // <-- 

    // requires using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    // Set password with the Secret Manager tool.
    // dotnet user-secrets set SeedUserPW <pw>

    var testUserPw = "fake_p4ssword_";

    await SeedData.Initialize(services, testUserPw);
}
```

I no longer get the error that AspNetRoles is already in the database.